# How to trigger a button in another aspx by closing the current aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have a situation to trigger a button in the previously opened aspx page and close the current aspx page

when i start the application, 
       form 1->form 2 . Note:Both the forms are opened
After performing some operation, form 2 should be closed and form 1 should be refreshed. For refresh i have button which i am suppose to trigger it from form 2

Comment: instead of that opening new page you can open New Web Form as Modal Popup of ASP.Net Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to update a flag in the querystring or the session, which will tell a JS ode placed on the other page to click on the button.

Comment: Thanks Rumen..I used the same and it was working fine.